# Angular 4 rest service returns a zip file. Need to download the zip file and save in downloads folder

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a angular4 service which have a rest api call which returns a zip file. I need to save the file in downloads. Can any body suggest me a method other than angular-file-saver?

Comment: `<a href="/url/to/your/service.zip">Download</a>`?

Comment: Actually you can wire up the button that calls the rest api to directly call the rest api from the HTML itself. Do you have any business logic happening before that?

Comment: yes, there is a complex logic before calling the rest service. i am able to get the response zip file but not sure how to map(observable map) the response of zip file and how to subscibe and download the file in file. Can anyone please help on that?

Comment: I am in similar situation. Did you ever resolve? @AyushSomani

Comment: yes i was able to achieve this using file-saver. Please follow the below steps:-
* run 'npm install file-saver --save'
* import {saveAs} from 'file-saver'; //in the ts file where you are writing the import code
* define a variable var filename="the name with which you need to download the zip"+".zip"
*inside subscribe use save as - subscribe(response => {
    saveAs(response, filename)
}